# Can you help identify the controller of smps

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, controller

Found on smps it is probebly the controller - but couldnt find it on google

Looks like it is writen 9202 834p4

[image]

Comment: Um... Not sure what's up with your image link, but it's something unrelated and changes with each page load.

Comment: Lol looks like stackexchange mixes picture uploaded to the site

Comment: Well you're not likely to get much help unless you fix it.

Comment: There is a link to an image on external server on the bottom of the question

Comment: Your image link appears to work, but you should insert the image inline with the built in tools so it shows up in your question without clicking and does not disappear over time.

Comment: Hey kh you are right but we are going off topic